# Datatable ,Javascript and Json

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable, jsonresponse

I have a Django Python webapp , i have a function :

```
def showreport(newrequest) :
        rep1 = get_report_data(newrequest,2)
        data={['columns':rep1[0],'rows':rep1[1]}
        return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
```

i call this function from javascript in HTML page , the data return is an array with two elements, 1 represent columns and the other the data.

I want to present in the HTML page the data in a DataTable object , and since the columns and data is dynamic i want to create the DataTable dynamically

In the HTML

In JavaScript 

    $(document).ready(function () {

```
 $("#showresults").on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
 $('#show_loading').show();
$('#theTable').hide();
froms = document.getElementById('startdate').value;
tos = document.getElementById('todate').value;        
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'showreport',
            data: {
                'start_date' : froms,
                'end_date' :tos,
                   'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

               $('#show_loading').hide();          
   var rowSet=data['rows'];
 var columnset =data['columns'];

       $('#theTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    searching: false,
    paging: false,
   "bInfo" : false,
 columns:  [columnset]  ,
    data: [rowSet]
   } ); 
$('#theTable').show();

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#show_loading').hide();
                alert("Error, please try again!");
            }
});  
        });    

    });
```

Now the problem i have is that the Columns are not presented and the data is presenting only 1 row and it is not separated to columns.

In inspect mode , i can see
{"rows": [["Test1", "Test2"],["Test3", "Test4"] etc..., "columns": ["col1","col2"]}

What am i doing wrong.

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an array of an array :)

try

**change this**

```
columns: [columnset],
data: [rowSet]
```

**to this**

```
columns: columnset,
data: rowSet
```

Comment: already tried it, i am getting DataTables warning: table id=theTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3  and the same results , columns are not shown and data is shown as 1 cloumn

Comment: Ok, the error cannot reinitialise is interesting. You shouldn't be calling DataTable on every click. You need to rewrite the code so that you create the table before the click event and if it's there kill it before reinit.

Comment: If you create a jsfiddle and send the link over I will edit it and try to make work for you. Instead of using AJAX just create a var with the data inside

Comment: I sloved it ,The solution is:
       for (i = 0; i < data['columns'].length; i++) {       
    newcolumns.push({"title":columnset[i]}); 
}
           for (i = 0; i < data['columns'].length; i++) { 
   
    newrows.push(rowSet[i]); 
}